# CC430 UART Reading Problem -Receive Interrupt Flag is Always '0'

Tags: c, interrupt, uart, msp430

I'm trying to establish UART communication. I can send data from CC430F6137 to other MCU .However I  couldn't handle receive operation. I'm sure that other MCU sends the data through UART Tx pin , but I couldn't get this datas from CC430 Rx pin.

My code is that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <msp430.h>
#include "cc430x613x.h"

char buffer_0[5] ;
char terminal_read();

int main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // stop watchdog timer
  UART_open();
  UCA0IE |= UCRXIE ;

  while(1)
  {
    terminal_read();
    // __delay_cycles(1e5);
  }
  return 0;
}

char terminal_read()
{
  char c ;
  while (!(UCA0IFG & UCRXIFG));
  c = UCA0RXBUF ;
  printf("%c" , &c);
  return UCA0RXBUF;
}


void terminal_write(char *info)
{
  unsigned int i;

  unsigned int len = strlen(info) ;
  for(i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
    UCA0TXBUF=info[i];
    __delay_cycles(10000);
  }
}

void UART_open()
{
  P1SEL |= BIT5 + BIT6;
  //UART Settings
  UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;
  UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL0 ; // ACLK
  UCA0BR0=3; //UCA0BR0 = 3 ; //32Khz / 9600 –>> 3
  UCA0BR1=0; //UCA0BR1=0; // BAUD 9600; ( UCABR1 * 256 ) + UCABR0 = UCABRx see "slau259e.pdf"
  
  UCA0MCTL=UCBRS0 + UCBRS1 ; // see "slau259e.pdf" page 602 //
  //UCA0MCTL =| BIT7 | BIT6 | BIT5 | BIT4 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT1 | BIT0 |
  // |------- UCBRFx --------------|----UCBRSx----------|UCOS16|
  // for 9600 baudrate at 32kHz UCBRFx = 0 , UCBRSx = 3 , UCOS16 = 0
  // | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
  // 0b00000110 = 0x06 = 6
  UCA0CTL1 &=~ UCSWRST;//
  // UCA0CTL1 |= UCDORM;
}

void UART_close()
{

  P1SEL &= ~(BIT5 + BIT6);
  P1DIR |= BIT5 + BIT6;
  P1OUT &= ~(BIT5 + BIT6);
  UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;
  UCA0CTL1 &=~ UCDORM;

}

char* String_int(int data)
{
  char* ret_data;
  ret_data = ltoa(data , buffer_0 , 10 );
  return ret_data;
}
```

What's wrong with my code? I always read the UCRXIFG as '0'. So 'terminal_read' function always stuck on this line.

Comment: Do you mean alternative functions of the 1.6 and 1.7 pins or another Rx and Tx pins to use? If you mean second , my MCU has only 1 UART port which already I use.

Comment: I'm sorry , it's 1.5 and 1.6 not 1.7. It just clerical error.

Comment: Where does the printf function prints to? Are you sure the interrupt flag is the problem? May the printf hang?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are polling for the interrupt flag in the *terminal_read()* function, then you don't need to enable interrupt with *UCA0IE |= UCRXIE;* because that will cause the CPU to go to the interrupt vector, which your code doesn't provide. Instead, remove the *UCA0IE |= UCRXIE;* and continue polling.

Also, the *printf()* will go to the terminal of the Debug window only if you have the JTAG debugger attached, otherwise it could get stuck. I agree with [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4915222/peter-paul-kiefer) that it could get stuck here if you don't have the debugger attached. Try removing that and replace with an LED blinker so you know the *terminal_read()* isn't getting stuck.